# How to view standard library functions in C++?

Tags: c++, function

For example, i want to see the code of function `toupper()` to understand how it works, is there any way? I have searched and opened `string.h` library, but didn't find anything.

Comment: `string.h` is a header, not a library.

Comment: @melpomene, Cool, how to see what's inside toupper()?

Comment: Depends on what library you're using. It's not like there's a single implementation shared by all C++ compilers.

Comment: a header can include other headers...

Comment: The best thing to do is try a debug version and trace into the function. This is one of the only ways to find a function in the source code in C++.

Comment: @QuentinUK: *"one of the only ways"*?

Comment: @Christian Hackl http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161442/does-one-of-the-only-actually-mean-anything

Answer (score 3):

From a strict language point of view, you cannot "see the code" of a standard function, because the C++ language standard only defines functions' prototypes and behaviours, not how they are implemented.

In fact, from a strict language point of view, a standard function like `toupper` does not even have to have source code, because a standard header, like `<string.h>` does not even have to be a file!

Of course, in *practice*, you will probably never encounter a C++ implementation in which standard headers are not files, because files are just a natural and simple implementation of headers. This means that in practice, for the header `<string.h>`, there is actually a C++ source file called "string.h" somewhere on your computer. **Just find it and open it.**

> I have searched and opened `string.h` library, but didn't find anything.

Then you have not looked close enough. Hint: This file most likely includes one or more other header files.

Note that if you actually looked for `toupper`, that function is not in `<string.h>` anyway. Look in `<ctype.h>` instead. cppreference.com is a good online reference to tell you which headers contain which functions.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper

Again, this does not mean that the corresponding header file of your compiler contains that function directly, but it may directly or indirectly include some other file which contains it.

---

In any case, **beware** of what you will see inside of your compiler's header files. It will usually be a lot more complicated than you may think, and, more importantly, it will often use constructs you are not allowed to use in your own code; after all, the code in those files is internal to the compiler implementation, and the compiler has a lot of privileges you don't have, for example using otherwise forbidden identifiers like `_STD_BEGIN`. Also expect a lot of completely non-standard `#pragma`s and other non-portable stuff.

Another important thing to keep in mind is that you are not supposed to dig through a function's implementation to find out what it does. In badly written software, i.e. software with confusing interfaces and no documentation (which exists everywhere in the real world), you unfortunately have to do this, provided you have access to the source code.

But C++ standard functions are perfectly documented and have, with some arguable exceptions, well-designed interfaces. It may be interesting, and educating, and sometimes even necessary for debugging, to look into their implementation on your system, but don't let this possibility keep you from learning two important software-engineering skills:

1. Reading documentation.
2. Programming to interfaces, not to implementations.

Comment: @Walter: For the purpose of this question, it doesn't make a difference because both are wrong. `<string.h>` is an officially deprecated synonym for `<cstring>`, containing all the `char`-pointer functions from C.

Comment: @Christian Hackl, Thank you, your answer helped me out very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, you could (not all realizations, maybe). For example, the glibc implementation [defines](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/ctype/ctype.c#50) `toupper` function as:

```
#define __ctype_toupper \
  ((int32_t *) _NL_CURRENT (LC_CTYPE, _NL_CTYPE_TOUPPER) + 128)

int
toupper (int c)
{
  return c >= -128 && c < 256 ? __ctype_toupper[c] : c;
}
```

Comment: @user3002386 What use is it to you to have this information? It's a horrible C code and not portable.

Comment: In what sense is that not portable? `_NL_CURRENT` is missing here as well as `LC_TYPE` and `_NL_CTYPE_TOUPPER`, so the implementation is incomplete. But what is dependent on the compiler or the operating system? Why should it be portable? Symbols with leader undescore and capital letters are compiler's property anyway?